# Django save method doesn't work despite successful POST request

Tags: python, jquery, django

I'm using jquery to send request to a Django form. I have this function in `views.py`:

```
@csrf_exempt
def update_ops(request):
    print('something something')
    ops_id = request.POST['id']
    instance = Ops.objects.all().filter(id=ops_id)
    form_qdict = QueryDict(request.POST['form_data'])
    form = OpsForm(form_qdict or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print('saved bro!')
        # return HttpResponseRedirect('/ops/')
    else:
        print('form is not valid')
    return render(request, 'ops_form.html', {'form': form})
```

`urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
url('^update_ops_form/', views.update_ops, name='update_ops_form')
]
```

the html form in `form.html`:

```
 <form action="{% url 'update_ops_form' %}" id="post-form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
 <!--some html form-->
</form>
```

and the script in `form.html`:

```
<script>
    var ops_id = $('#ops_id').text()
    console.log(ops_id)

    $("#post-form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action
        var post_url = $(this).attr("action");
        console.log(post_url)//get form action url
        var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST method
        var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //Encode form elements for submission
        console.log(form_data)
        $.ajax({
            url: post_url,
            type: request_method,
            data: {'id':ops_id,'form_data':form_data}
        })
    });
</script>
```

What I want to do is to update an instance of the Ops Model with form using jquery. The POST request is successful, but it doesn't update the instance that I changed. The only possible reason for the error that I know of is because the url in `action` parameter of the html form doesn't match the url that maps to the `update_ops()` function in `views.py`, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Also I'm able to view the Form pre-populated with data from the Model, so I don't think the problem is from declaring those 2. I'm fairly new to Django and Jquery so thank you if you can spend some time and tell me what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know what's wrong with the `save()` function. But my workaround is to add `commit=False` and manually set the `id` to the `ops_id` before commit like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def update_ops(request):
    ops_id = request.POST['id']
    instance = Ops.objects.get(pk=ops_id)
    form_qdict = QueryDict(request.POST['form_data'])
    form = OpsForm(form_qdict or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit = False)
        obj.id = ops_id
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/ops/')
    else:
        print('form is not valid')

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `OpsForm` is a `ModelForm` and not a `Form`, I suspect the problem is how you're fetching `instance`. Currently it's being set to a `QuerySet`. You want the actual instance:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
instance = get_object_or_404(Ops, id=ops_id)
```

If you'd prefer to do your own error handling if the instance doesn't exist then:

```
instance = Ops.objects.filter(id=ops_id).first()
```

If it doesn't exist, `instance` will be set to `None`.

Edit:

The other thing you should strongly consider doing is to move the id of the `Ops` instance into the url, then the request body can just be the form and doesn't have to be wrapped in another object. The [documentation covers urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/) pretty well.

This would change your view to:

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseForbidden
def update_ops(request, ops_id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Ops, ops_id)
    if request.method != "POST":
        raise HttpResponseForbidden
    form = OpsForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print('saved bro!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/ops/')
    else:
        print('form is not valid')
    return render(request, 'ops_form.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
    path('update_ops_form/<int:ops_id>', views.update_ops, name='update_ops_form')
]
```

template

```
<form action="{% url 'update_ops_form' ops_id=ops.id %}" id="post-form" method="post">
```

script:

```
<script>
    $("#post-form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action
        var post_url = $(this).attr("action");
        console.log(post_url)//get form action url
        var request_method = $(this).attr("method"); //get form GET/POST 
        console.log(form_data)
        $.ajax({
            url: post_url,
            type: request_method,
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the type of my instance is `<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>` so I guess it's valid. And you are right, it's a `ModelForm`, I couldn't tell the difference yet.

Comment: `instance` should be an instance of `Ops` not `QuerySet`.

Comment: I changed it to `instance = Ops.objects.all().filter(id=ops_id).first()` and get the `Ops` datatype but the problem is still there

Comment: @duyanhhoang I reworked the answer to make use of url params. Doing that simplifies the rest of the work.